# how can I add a new action to a controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, action

I used the following in routes to add a new action to my Email controller:

```
   map.resources :emails, :member => { :newfwd => :put}
```

The expected result was that newfwd_email_path(:id => 1) would generate the following urL:  emails/1/newfwd

It does.  But I get an error, it treats '1' as an action and 'newfwd' as an id.  I want '1' to be interpreted as the id for emails, upon which the newfwd action acts.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. (Note: I am using Rails 2.3.8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
link_to newfwd_email_path(1), :method => :put
```

`:id => 1` is as good as `1` ;)

Comment: I see -- how come putting the method in the routes doesn't work?  Let me try this out....

Answer (score 0):

you do not need to pass a hash to the newfwd_email_path method. Try

```
newfwd_email_path(1)
```

EDIT: you also need to use :method => :put to ensure that the PUT verb is used when request is received on the server and routing comes into effect.

Comment: I se, thanks -- do you know why?  seems like if I put it explicitly in the routes, it should work....?